# Common factor in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, math, algebra

I'm trying to factorize an equation by finding the common factor, for example:

```
4x+2y = 2(2x+y)
```

so basically between

```
If n1 <> n2 Then
```

and

```
End If
```

is where the problem is since I don't know what to type.

i tried doing it like this:

```vb
if n1/n2 = whole number 
n3 = n1/n2
MsgBox(n3 & "(" & l1 & "+" & l2 & ")")
```

but I couldn't figure out the whole number code, and when I did get it to work I realized that it wouldn't also divide a number, so if the question was:

```
4x+2y
```

the answer would be:

```
2(2x+y)
```

but the computer gave me:

```
2(x+y)
```

So far I have:

```vb
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim n1 As Integer
        Dim n2 As Integer
        Dim l1 As String
        Dim l2 As String

        n1 = InputBox("what is the first number ")
        l1 = InputBox("what is the first letter ")
        n2 = InputBox("what is the second number ")
        l2 = InputBox("what is the second letter ")

        If n1 = n2 Then
            MsgBox(n1 & "(" & l1 & "+" & l2 & ")")
        End If
        If n1 <> n2 Then

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want it to factorize it so it is correct.

If the question is:

```
4x+12y
```

I want it to be:

```
4(x+3y)
```

rather than what I have been getting which is:

```
4(x+y)
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem. What you would need right now is some sound pseudocode: if you can do this by hand, you know how to do it. You have to produce a step-by-step how-to that you will be able to code afterward.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: First you need to get the factors of each of the coefficients. I believe this will require recursion. If you are not familiar with recursive functions you will need to do some research.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are looking for is:

```
If n1 <> n2 Then        
    If n1 Mod n2 = 0 Then
        Dim n3 = n1 / n2
        MsgBox(n3 & "(" & (n1 / n3) & l1 & "+" & (n2 / n3) & l2 & ")")
    End If
End If
```

The modulo operator `Mod` gives the remainder of integer division. Hence, if `n1 Mod n2` is zero, then `n2` is a divisor of `n1`. Then, in your final result, you need to cancel out `n3`.

However, this is not exactly what you want to do. Because this would also not change anything for the input `6x + 4y`. What you want to do is factor out the greatest common divisor. This can be calculated with the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Here is the full code:

```
Private Function GreatestCommonDivisor(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    If a = 0 Then Return b
    Return GreatestCommonDivisor(b Mod a, a)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim n1 As Integer
    Dim n2 As Integer
    Dim l1 As String
    Dim l2 As String

    n1 = InputBox("what is the first number ")
    l1 = InputBox("what is the first letter ")
    n2 = InputBox("what is the second number ")
    l2 = InputBox("what is the second letter ")

    Dim n3 = GreatestCommonDivisor(n1, n2)
    MsgBox(n3 & "(" & (n1 / n3) & l1 & "+" & (n2 / n3) & l2 & ")")
End Sub
```

This will print `2(2x + 1y)` for `4x + 2y` and `2(3x + 2y)` for `6x + 4y`.